# DB2 sql - Sum of current month, quarter and year data from a table of monthly data

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table of monthly data having three primary keys. These are stored as one record at monthly level considering these 3 primary keys. I would like to select

1. sum of current month data
2. sum of current quarter data
3. sum of current year data

.

```
Source Table 
===========  
monthenddate key1 key2 key3 Data1  updated  
11/30        1     2     3    50    11/1  
10/30        1     2     3    50    10/1  
1/31         1     2     3    50    1/1  

target Table  
===========  
key1 key2 key3 Month   Qtr    Yr    updated  
 1     2     3    50   100    150    11/1
```

Could anybody please help

Comment: Do you need the output in one row? Not absolutely sure about the structure of the table. I would recommend using `GROUP BY` to group at different time frames. Can you share the structure of the table and expected output?

Comment: Yes output should be one row, I have updated the structure above, let me know whether that makes sense, I would like to see the output without giving a time filter, if that's possible

Comment: So, one row for `January, Qtr, Year`, and Feb and Mar ... Dec . e.g. 12 rows repeating the same Year value? Would you provide a mock-up of this just to satisfy yourself that it makes sense.

Comment: I will only need one row in the target table for sum(current month data), sum(current quarter data),sum(current year data). This is a current view table

Comment: So is "current month" the month "right now" or the month "just past"?

Comment: Current month, quarter and year as of current date not previous month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db2 is kinda easy with this stuff the api is just named what you would expect:

```
select key1, key2, key3,
  sum(case when month(updated) = month(current date) then data1 else 0 end) as Month,
  sum(case when quarter(updated) = quarter(current date) then data1 else 0 end) as Qtr,
  sum(case when year(updated) = year(current date) then data1 else 0 end) as Yr,
  max(updated) as updated
from source_table
-- select just this year
where year(updated) = year(current date)
group by key1, key2, key3
```

Comment: That worked perfectly fine, could you also please let me know if I need to alter this for all quarters and years?

Comment: @RRR -- no idea what you mean.

Comment: The above query is to find the aggregate for only current month. But if I need to find the sum monthly, quarterly and yearly for all existing monthly data in the source table how should this be altered?

Comment: @RRR -- this gives you current month, current quarter and current year.  If you have a different question you need to ask another question -- at the very least I need an example of your expected output because words like this don't make a requirement I can write to.

Comment: Sure, but I'm getting an error to the above query. MONTH(CURRENT DATE) and QUARTER(CURRENT DATE) is taking current month and quarter of any year. its not considering the year. for eg: 10/20/2016 is getting added to the current quarter

Comment: i think i figure it out by adding and year and condition

Comment: @RRR -- oh I see -- if you have more data in the table... I'll show you how to select just the current year.